# Is there a python linter that checks if the type hint comes from the typing module?

Tags: python, type-hinting, lint, pylint

I am looking for a python linter that checks if type hints come from the typing module.

As in, this:

```py
def  func(arg: list)-> None:
   """ does something """
```

should be:

```py
from typing import List

def  func(arg: List)-> None:
   """ does something """
```

Comment: FYI, `typing.List` is deprecated now that `list` is generic. I'm not sure why this is something you'd want to require.

Comment: Why should it be? They both work, and List is deprecated since list gained generic support in 3.9: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.List.

Comment: `list` alone has *always* worked, and in older versions, trying to write `list[int]` instead of `List[int]` is just an error, not a matter of style.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. I wanted to avoid the team using two different conventions, and I thought that list[int] didn't work. Now that it does, and List is deprecated, the answer is clearly moving towards using list[int]. The question now remains how to check that List[int] is not used then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer, you can use [mypy](https://mypy-lang.org/).
On a note `typing.List` is deprecated since [3.9](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.List)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that typing built-ins was deprecated. That's super useful to know.

Comment: You can use pylint with https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/technical_reference/extensions.html#pylint-extensions-typing to check for those deprecated aliases.